# como poner una condicional dentro de echo td php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7, condiciones, php5

Un saludo cordial estimados amigos, Tengo una dificultad en insertar una condicional segun el numero de evaluacion que tengo de los cuales deseo cambiar las notas de numero a letras dentro de un echo td. espero su pronta ayuda saludos.

Dejo el codigo:

```html
$tb_miperu_notas = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, nota 
                                                                    FROM tb_miperu_notas 
                                                                    WHERE id_alumno = ".$alumno['id']." 
                                                                    AND id_materia = ".$id_materia);
                                $tb_miperu_notas->execute();
                                $tb_miperu_notas = $tb_miperu_notas->fetchAll();
                                $nota_media=0;
                                
                                foreach ($tb_miperu_notas as $eval => $nota) {
                                        $nota_media += $nota['nota']/4;

                                     echo '<td align="center">
                                            <input type="hidden" 
                                            name="nota'.$eval.'" value="'. $nota['nota'] . '" >'. $nota['nota'] . '</td>';
                                        
                                        if ($nota['nota'] >= 18) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#1146DE; font-weight: bold;" >AD</p>';
                                        
                                        } else if ($nota['nota'] >= 14) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#0E749A; font-weight: bold;" >A</p>';
                                        
                                        } else if ($nota['nota'] >= 11) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#B9A60B; font-weight: bold;" >B</p>';
                                        
                                        } else if ($nota['nota'] >= 1) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#B90C05; font-weight: bold;" >C</p>';
                            
                                        } else if ($nota['nota'] >= 0) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#B90C05; font-weight: bold;" >NSP</p>';
                                        }
                         
                                }
```

Por lo tanto aqui les dejo la foto lo que necesito es cambiar esas notas  segun las condionales en letras

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Lo que intento es que dentro del echo td deseo insertar la condionales pero me sale error. echo

dejo la tabla.

```html
<table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>NRO</th>
                        <th>CODIGO </th>
                        <th>APELLIDOS Y NOMBRES</th>
                        <th>TA</th>
                        <th>EP</th>
                        <th>EF</th>
                        <th>AV</th>
                        <th>PROMEDIO</th>
                        <th>LETRAS</th>
                        <th>OBSERVACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <?php foreach ($alumnos as $index => $alumno) :?>
           
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><?php echo $i++ ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $alumno['dni'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $alumno['apellido_paterno']." ".$alumno['apellido_materno'].", ".$alumno['nombres'] ?></td>
           
                            <?php
                                //escribiendo las notas en columnas
                                $tb_miperu_notas = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, nota 
                                                                    FROM tb_miperu_notas 
                                                                    WHERE id_alumno = ".$alumno['id']." 
                                                                    AND id_materia = ".$id_materia);
                                $tb_miperu_notas->execute();
                                $tb_miperu_notas = $tb_miperu_notas->fetchAll();
                                $nota_media=0;
                                
                                foreach ($tb_miperu_notas as $eval => $nota) {
                                        $nota_media += $nota['nota']/4;

                                    echo '<td align="center"><input type="hidden" 
                                            name="nota'.$eval.'" value="'. $nota['nota'] . '" >'. $nota['nota'] .  

                                        if ($nota['nota'] >= 18) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#1146DE; font-weight: bold;" >AD</p>';
                                        
                                        } else if ($nota['nota'] >= 14) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#0E749A; font-weight: bold;" >A</p>';
                                        
                                        } else if ($nota['nota'] >= 11) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#B9A60B; font-weight: bold;" >B</p>';
                                        
                                        } else if ($nota['nota'] >= 1) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#B90C05; font-weight: bold;" >C</p>';
                            
                                        } else if ($nota['nota'] >= 0) {
                                            echo '<p style="color:#B90C05; font-weight: bold;" >NSP</p>';
                                        }
                                    } '</td>';


                                }
                                           
                            echo '<td align="center">'.number_format($nota_media).'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $alumno['observaciones']. '</td>';
                            ?>
            
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

segun las codionales if necesito cambiar los numero por letras en mi tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo tenes que pensar al revez. Si `nota < 1 => NSP`, si `nota < 11 => C`, etc.

Comment: Darío Hj, estás cerrando el `td` antes de los `if`. Ese `</td>` debería ir después del último `else if`. Lo que no entiendo es la imagen que adjuntas, porque ahí sale una tabla de diferentes alumnos y en realidad tu consulta está trabajando solo para uno. También habría que ver dónde inicias y cierras cada fila (`<tr>`), pero me imagino que si sólo quieres una, sería antes y después del código que muestras.

Comment: Muchas gracias [Marcos] , Excelente.

Comment: Estimado VFG afirmativo lo que estoy haciendo es un foreach y un echo td para insertar las 4 evaluaciones, pero deseo insetar una condicional segun las notas para que se cambien por letras segun su calificacion mas abajo le dejo la tabla muchas gracias por su aporte.